# WMS Layer not rendered properly on all zoom levels

Tags: javascript, openlayers, postgis, geoserver, wms

I have configured a PostgreSQL v9.5.12 database with the PostGIS v2.4.2 extension. I use GeoServer v2.13.1 to render the tables of the database as WMS Layers and visualise them in a webapp using Openlayers (v4.6.5). The projection used is [EPSG:31255](https://epsg.io/31255).

However the WMS Layers are not displayed properly on all zoom levels. Sometimes tiles are cut off (see screenshot 1) or not every point in a layer is rendered (see screenshot 2). On some levels, especially when zoomed in, the layer isn't displayed at all. The layers are displayed properly in GeoServer itself and when add them to qGIS.

I use this setup and code for other layers too and it works smoothly, however these layers use a different projection (ESPG:4326).

How can I fix this?

[image: WMS Example 1]
Screenshot 1 (part of outline on the right side is cut off)

[image: WMS Example 2]
Screenshot 2 (green dots in between are missing)

EDIT:
Here is a code snippet that include the definition of EPSG:31255, without actually using it for the wmsSource.

```
    // proj4js custom projection        
    proj4.defs("EPSG:31255","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=13.33333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs");
    var proj31255 = ol.proj.get('EPSG:31255');
    proj31255.setExtent([-115771.3204, 130037.7189, 115359.4571, 408002.5351]);

    var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: geoserver_getcapabilities_url + geoserver_workspace + '/wms?',
        params: {
            'LAYERS': wms_layer_name
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        //projection: 'EPSG:31255'
    });

    var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: wmsSource,
        name: 'selected_wms_layer',
        visible: true
    }); 

    var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    var view = new ol.View({
        center: map_centre,
        zoom: initial_zoom_level,
        projection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });

    /** Set-up the map */
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [osmLayer, wmsLayer, point_layer],
        overlays: [overlay],
        view: view,
        loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
        loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
            new ol.control.OverviewMap()
        ])
    });
```

Comment: EPSG:4326 is built-in in OpenLayers, I don't think this is the case for 31255. You may double-check the definition of your projection (Are you using proj4js btw?)
Also, using network debug tab, can you confirm that there's no failure in the WMS tiles requests ?

Is there a possibility of having a minimal code to dig further on your problem ?

Comment: Indeed I didn't declare the EPSG:31255 using proj4s. I now added that part, but the layer isn't visible at all anymore. Do I need to change the view of the map. I followed the answer here and only changed the projection of the WMS not, but not of the map itself: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143883/openlayers-3-wms-custom-projection-wrong-extent

Comment: Apparently the layer is still rendered on the map, just not where it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual cause of issues like this is using a standard WMS as the base for a `TileWMS` layer. This can cause all sorts of issues both in the client and the server.

Make use of the provided WMTS or TMS endpoints to request tiles from GeoServer/GeoWebCache. For example this [page](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-layer-from-capabilities.html) shows how to do it right.

Comment: I deviated a little from answer by instead using an ImageWMS, which solved the issue (http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.ImageWMS.html).

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR : [An excellent working example is available on the OpenLayers WebSite](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection.html?q=reproject)

(In the following examples, the positions I used should be somewhere in Austria)

First, let's ensure that the EPSG:31255 is correctly set. As said in the comment, I recommend you to use proj4js, it will make your life easier if you have to deal with projections.

Once you've imported the proj4js library into your app, declare the EPSG:31255 projection as follow:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:31255","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=13.33333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs");
```

(You can import a lot of projections in proj4js using [epsg.io](http://epsg.io/) as a source : https://epsg.io/31255.js )

> Hint: Import proj4js **before** OpenLayers, and it will be used without
>   extra work in OpenLayers.

### First case : Deal with one projection for all layers

Now, we need to create or update the OpenLayers map with a view that take this new projection into account.

```
let myMap = new ol.Map({
        target: myDOMElement,
        layers: [...],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([50163.181015, 255280.097217]),
            zoom: 5,
            projection: 'EPSG:31255'
        })
    });
```

Now, you may have some hard times setting a correct center, because you must set its coordinates in the EPSG:31255 projection.

To make it easier, I do recommend to use a Transform based on EPSG:4326, for instance.

```
view: new ol.View({
    // Converts from coordinates known in EPSG:4326 to coordinates in EPSG:31255
    center: ol.proj.transform([13.7548828125, 47.43896484375], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:31255'),
    zoom: 5,
    projection: 'EPSG:31255' // Projection you want the map to use
})
```

### Second Case : Dealing with different projections

So what if you have different projections for different layers ?

Simply specify them in your TileWMS (ensure they all have been declared).

```
let myWMSSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: myURL,
    params: {
        'LAYERS': 'myCustomLayer'
    },
    serverType: 'geoserver',
    projection: 'EPSG:31255' // Declare the projection the source is in.
});
```

OpenLayers should automatically reproject them in your map projection.

### Concrete example: Using your layer on top of an OSM Map

```
/** Set a source */
let myWMSSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: myURL,
    params: {
        'LAYERS': 'myCustomLayer'
    },
    serverType: 'geoserver',
    projection: 'EPSG:31255'
});

/** Create a custom tile layer */
let myLayerTile = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: myWMSSource,
    name: 'MyTile',
    visible: true
});

/**
 * Create a layer using OSM.
 * Note that ol.source.OSM uses EPSG:3857
 */
let OSMLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

/** Set-up the map */
let myMap = new ol.Map({
    target: DOMElement,
    layers: [OSMLayer, myLayerTile],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([1549123.872774, 6044640.196792]),
        zoom: 1,
        projection: 'EPSG:3857'
    }),
    loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
    loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.OverviewMap()
    ])
});
```

Comment: GeoServer will make a better and faster job of reprojecting vector data than OpenLayers will so always request your tiles in the map projection.

Comment: The provided example suggests that I need to set the extent of the projection too. Is this required or optional? Currently it doesn't work either way.

Comment: @IanTurton : That is indeed true if you don't need to switch projections once everything has been loaded. Otherwise, OL reprojections are good enough to avoid re-requesting tiles over the network.

stopopol: I don't think specifying the extent is required. Could you please provide us with some more insight like code ? Without more information, it's not easy finding the source of the problem.

Comment: This issue really goes over my head. If I carefully follow your instructions the issue actually gets worse. The layers are only visible on very few zoom levels. As soon as I zoom in they disappear altogether. If I omit the projection definition, they are displayed better, yet still pretty badly. The projection declaration itself works. I tested that using console.log(ol.proj.fromLonLat([5.2, 52.25], 'EPSG:31255'));